# How to convert char* into std::u8string?

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++20, c-strings, stdstring

## Intro

If I catch an exception, I want to convert the error message, which is returned as a C-style string by the `what()` method, into a `std::u8string` (a UTF-8 string). For example: `std::u8string(error.what());`

## Problem

How can I convert a `char*` into a `std::u8string`?

## Additional Information

- I only catch exceptions from the standard library, boost and eigen.
- My application is Windows dependent, so the solution doesn't need to be portable.

Comment: Do you know how the C-string you are receiving is encoded? Is it UTF-8 or Latin-1?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I added some additional information. I don't know exactly the source encoding.

Comment: Unfortunately without knowing the source encoding you *fundamentally* can't convert it to a UTF-8 string. In general you can probably either make some assumptions and go with Sam's answer (based on the libraries you are using, I'd say that the source encoding is almost certainly going to be UTF-8 or even Latin-1), or you can try to guess the encoding based on actual data, though that's very error-prone and a lot of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the constructor that takes a beginning and an ending iterator for the sequence that defines the string.

```
#include <cstring>

// ...

auto cstr=error.what();

std::u8string str{cstr, cstr+strlen(cstr)};
```